# Связывание свойства Position MediaElement'а

Tags: wpf, c#

Хотелось бы связать свойство Position у MediaElement на поле Value слайдера, примерно так:

```
<MediaElement Position="{Binding Path=Value, Element=Slider}" />
```

Но данный код не работает, подскажите, как проще всего это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Через `DataBinding` не получится, так как `MediaElement.Position` не является `DependencyProperty`.

На MSDN есть [пример создания панели контролов для управления MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx).

Надеюсь, поможет.

Answer (score 0):

```
<MediaElement Position="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=Slider}" />
```

Comment: Минус за невнимательность, `MediaElement.Position` не является DependencyProperty, поэтому через DataBinding его установить нельзя.

Comment: Эт я понял.. я имел в виду, что ошибка в синтаксисе: не  Element=Slider, а ElementName=Slider должно быть..