# Привязка слайдера к MediaElement

Tags: c#, slider, wpf, windows-phone-7

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Есть некоторые проблемы с работой с MediaElement-ом и слайдером в Windows Phone.

Есть медиаЭлемент:

```
<MediaElement Name="mediaFile" даьшемногопараметров />
```

и есть слайдер.

```
<Slider Name="sliderMedia" тожемногопараметров/>
```

Соответственно, надо слайдер привязать к медиаэлементу.
Я решил сделать это через таймер.

```
private DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = new TimeSpan(200) };



timer.Tick +=new EventHandler(timer_Tick);




 private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // двигаем слайдер.
            sliderMedia.Value = mediaFile.Position.TotalSeconds;
            // Что-то там делаем дальше.
        }
```

И собственно вопрос:

Допустим, я хочу переместиться в некую позицию медиа файла по клику/перетаскиванию слайдера.

Ну, например, можно сделать так:

```
private void sliderMedia_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        mediaFile.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sliderMedia.Value);
    }
```

Но тогда сюда будет заход при каждом тике (value то изменяется).

Как показала проверка, при этом из динамиков (проверял на аудио файле) слышится довольно
стремная хренотень(по другому и описать не могу) :)

Как это можно исправить?

1) Можно ли как-то по другому привязать слайдер к mediaElement? Например использовать  Position="{Binding}"?

С binding похоже не получится, аналогично [вот этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8170/%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-position-mediaelement-%D0%B0)

2) Можно ли использовать другой метод, кроме ValueChanged?

3) Можно ли вписать в этот ValueChanged какое-нибудь условие, чтоб срабатывало только при ручном перемещении.

Ну или, в крайнем случае, при остановленном медиа, что-то вроде:

```
if (!timer.IsRunning)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный прием в таком случае - добавление булевого флага.
В коде контрола:

```
bool ignoreChange = false;
```

В sliderMedia_ValueChanged:

```
if(ignoreChagne) return;
//дальше код
```

В timer_Tick:

```
ignoreChange = true;
mediaFile.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sliderMedia.Value);
ignoreChange = false;
```

Comment: Все так. Только sliderMedia_ValueChanged имеет тип void, и там будет скорее 

    if (!ignoreChange)
                try
                {
                    mediaFile.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sliderMedia.Value);
                }

Принимаю ответ.

Comment: return - это выход из функции без возврата значения, фактически читается как "вернуть ничего".